# SQL to find dominant page visited by most users in a given time-range by medium?

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I need to identify that for a particular interval of time, which are the top 3 pages visited and their total visits by all the users who performed a particular event called 'Checkout' based on medium.

The table name is event_table in AWS athena and the columns are user_id, medium, event_name, event_date.

I have written the following sql to populated all the pages visited by a user based on medium and total visits.

```
select medium, page_path, count(page_path)
from events_table 
where date_parse(event_date,'%Y-%m-%d') >= date_parse('2022-09-16','%Y-%m-%d')
  and date_parse(event_date,'%Y-%m-%d') <= date_parse('2022-09-22','%Y-%m-%d')
  and event_name = 'Checkout'
  and user_id = '002300-166240'
group by 1, 2
order by 2 desc
```

How to extend above sql to list out top 3 most visited pages based on medium by considering all the users?

Sample data:

```
medium  page_path                     _col2
Traffic /collectibles/all               168
Traffic /collectibles/home              2
Traffic /products/multi-config          5
Traffic /products/diamond-ring          1
google  /products/solid-original        6
Traffic /collectibles/shop              1
google  /collectibles/all-hairdryers    85
```

Comment: Please add sample data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL syntax greatest-n-per-group + aggregation in athena](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52582919/sql-syntax-greatest-n-per-group-aggregation-in-athena)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - pasted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number` (or `rank` or `dense_rank` depending on requirements for handling items with the same count) [window function](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html) with partition and ordering:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(medium, page_path, cnt) AS (
 values ('Traffic' ,'/collectibles/all',               168),
    ('Traffic' ,'/collectibles/home',              2),
    ('Traffic' ,'/products/multi-config',         5),
    ('Traffic' ,'/products/diamond-ring',         1),
    ('google' ,'/products/solid-original',        6),
    ('Traffic' ,'/collectibles/shop',              1),
    ('google' ,'/collectibles/all-hairdryers',    85)
)

-- query
select medium, page_path, cnt
from (
    select *,
           row_number() over (partition by medium order by cnt desc) ord
    from dataset)
where ord <= 3;
```

Output:

| medium | page_path | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Traffic | /collectibles/all | 168 |
| Traffic | /products/multi-config | 5 |
| Traffic | /collectibles/home | 2 |
| google | /collectibles/all-hairdryers | 85 |
| google | /products/solid-original | 6 |

Comment: the user_id column is missing in the dataset. I have given you the dataset for 1 user only. Similarly, multiple user_id can have multiple such rows.

Comment: @azaveri7 nice to know. Next time please provide valid sample data.

Comment: @azaveri7 also you have wrote that you want "to list out top 3 most visited pages based on medium by considering all the users". This does not need info about users cause it effectively ignored (i.e. grouping by `medium` and `page_path` effectively covers that). Just change `dataset` definition to your original query (without filtering by user).